# MVC - refresh controller SQL data model from View?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC, have some experience in webforms.

I currently have an ActionResult function in my controller that binds all my SQL data to a model, which then I can then successfully build a dataview from in the view.

My issue is that to have everything work properly, I need to call my ActionResult directly in the controller before rendering the page, and this works just fine:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Bind_grid();
        return View();
    }

    public class My_Table
    {
            public string info_a { get; set; }
            public string info_b { get; set; }
            public string mod_id { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Bind_grid()
    {
        SqlConnection checkitem = new SqlConnection("Data Source=[IPADDRESS];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password");
        string query = "SELECT id, info_a, info_b FROM [my_db].[dbo].[ref_index]";
        SqlCommand execute = new SqlCommand(query, checkitem);
        var model = new List<My_Table>();
        using (checkitem)
        {
            checkitem.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = execute.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                var table = new My_Table();

                table.info_a = rdr["info_a"].ToString();
                table.info_b = rdr["info_b"].ToString();
                table.mod_id = rdr["id"].ToString();
                model.Add(table);
            }
            checkitem.Close();
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I am wondering how to refresh the model from the view instead of requiring it to be ran before returning the view, I've tried AJAX calls and  @HTML.Action calls to Bind_grid, but I can't seem to get the page to refresh the data.

Any suggestions in running Bind_grid from a view to refresh the model?

Currently I try this:

```
function bind_data() {
          $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Bind_grid")',
            method: 'POST',
        });
        @{ 
            int p = 0;
            foreach (var d in Model)
            {
                @:console.log(@d.mod_id);
                p++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I set a javascript interval for 10 seconds to run the bind_data() function, 
remove some IDs from the SQL database between intervals,
but the data written to the console is still the original fetched, not the refreshed data.

If I manually refresh the page (F5), I get a correct update of data.

I'm guessing I need to do some kind of partial postback to refresh the razor data, but am not sure the best way to do it in MVC.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your ajax call is just calling the method and returning the view, but your do not do anything with it (you need to update the DOM in the ajax success callback). And your loop is razor (server side ) code - its just looping through the original model

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the jquery load method, call in your JavaScript interval

```
$("#grid").load("bind_grid");
```

Comment: How would i refresh the data at intervals in the view?  I've revised my question showing how I attempt to refresh, but the data never gets updated unless I manually refresh (F5) the page.

Comment: Isn't that doing the same thing as the ajax request (albeit, cleaner)?...I know that the bind_grid function IS working, as I have debug code writing to the console in the codebehind when it runs, it's just not updating on the view,  I believe it's because, although the function IS being called each time, the razor block is static to the page, when I need it to re-calculate on every call to the bind_data function, which I believe is where the trouble resides.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by doing all processing in the codebehind, changed the Bind_grid()
to JsonResult, returning Json(model.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
Was able to do successful pulls via ajax request.